# How to send video files as json data. (Not the file name or path but content) to Android

Tags: php, android, json, video

I'm using a restful webservice developed in php. The webservice will send data images. For images it will send the image name and we will prepare the url of the image on fly to download it. But  now there is a requirement to download video files. We can follow the same way like downloading images (ex: image name = "myimage1.jpeg" url=www.xyz.com/images/myimage1.jpeg", we will read this directly and create file locally), but want to know is there any way from php to send the data like binary string from php and convert it into movie file at Android end.

(Can we send images as json data from php webservice. Please give some code)

Note: How to send Images/Videos files from restful webservice as json data

Comment: Possible in theory, but the amount of data you would need to transmit would explode. It would take ages! However if you still want to give it a try - have look at Base64.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, as the data must be transferred completely before you can do anything with it. Instead of "streaming" the video, you need to download it first before you can even start showing it.

Comment: What would be your assumed benefit when embedding the video data into JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("/file")
public class DownloadVideoREST {

    private static final String VIDEO_FILE = "E:\\xyz.flv";


    @GET
    @Path("/video")
    @Produces("video/flv")
    public Response getVideoFile() {

        File file = new File(VIDEO_FILE);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"abc.flv\"");
        return response.build();

    }



        @GET
        @Path("/{fileName}/video")
        @Produces("video/flv")
        public Response getFileInVideoFormat(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName)
        {
            System.out.println("File requested is : " + fileName);


            if(fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty())
            {
                ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
                return response.build();
            }


            File file = new File("c:/abc.flv");

            ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.flv");
            return response.build();
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at all. This is Java sending a video File as a binary-stream attachment. No PHP, no JSON

Answer (score 4):

Of course you could send video-Data in JSON, but since JSON is essentially a String-Format with several reserved Characters you will have to encode the video-data.
You could use any scheme you like - but BASE64 is a widely accepted Standard so I would use it.

Just create a JSON-String object and fill it with the BASE-64 encoded Video Data.

But beware of Buffer-Overflows!!! Because many JSON-Implementations will usually not expect giant Data-Elements in JSON it may be advisable to break the Data-Stream into several smaller Chunks and deliver them one at a time... Of course you could also just stream the JSON-Data itself, but as far as I know most JSON Stacks operate serially, since you can only parse a valid JSON-String if it is complete.

So the best thing performance wise (if you REALLY WANT to pack the video Data into JSON, which is clearly not what JSON was ever intended for, and there should be better solutions for almost all setups) should be to BASE64 Encode the Video in a Stream, so you can read Chunks of it into Memory, pack them into JSON-Strings and send these to the Server, which can use these Chunks to stream the Video to a file or play it, or reconstruct it in memory...

@BSON was mentioned before - it could be advisable to use it, since the JSON-Data will be compressed. But it doesn't change the fact you have to encode your Video-Data in an unfavorable format, which will bloat up the transmitted data and will cost its fair share of performance on BOTH ENDS!

---

But I can imagine Scenarios where using JSON for video transmission could be advisable. If you have a high number of small videos (small jingles, or video fragments, which the user can select and collate) then a solid easy to handle data structure to administrate these videos could be well worth the extra transfer cost...

Answer (score 3):

As ChriZzZ stated, it's inadvisable (and not really natively supported) in JSON.

However, you may consider using [BSON (Binary JSON)](http://bsonspec.org/). Specifically for a PHP implementation, the site provides a link to [Mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver), so you may want to check that out. Unfortunately, I have no code to provide.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful to you:

**PHP Code (video.php)**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
$video_name = $_GET['name'];
$path = "/path/to/videos/folder/$video_name"; //ex: video.mp4

$size=filesize($path);

$fm=@fopen($path,'rb');
if(!$fm) {
  // You can also redirect here
  header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  die();
}

$begin=0;
$end=$size;

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
  if(preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches)) {
    $begin=intval($matches[0]);
    if(!empty($matches[1])) {
      $end=intval($matches[1]);
    }
  }
}

if($begin>0||$end<$size)
  header('HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content');
else
  header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');

header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.($end-$begin));
header("Content-Disposition: inline;");
header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header('Connection: close');

$cur=$begin;
fseek($fm,$begin,0);

while(!feof($fm)&&$cur<$end&&(connection_status()==0))
{ print fread($fm,min(1024*16,$end-$cur));
  $cur+=1024*16;
  usleep(1000);
}
die();
}else{
    echo "Please provide a Video name (name=)";
}
?>
```

**Java Code (Download and Save video to SDCARD):**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;


public class VideoSaveSDCARD extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ProgressBack PB = new ProgressBack();
        PB.execute("");
    }

    class ProgressBack extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
         ProgressDialog PD;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            PD= ProgressDialog.show(LoginPage.this,null, "Please Wait ...", true);
            PD.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        DownloadFile("http://yourserver/video.php?name=video.mp4","video.mp4");            

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            PD.dismiss();

        }

    }



    public void DownloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
        try {
            String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Video";
            File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
            RootFile.mkdir();
            // File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(RootFile,
                    fileName));
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {                          
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);               
            }       
            f.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This is normal practice.This is what we are doing. But what i was looking for is, is there any way to send image/video as part of json data itself (Not just names of image/video). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sending binary data in JSON from PHP is very simple:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
echo json_encode(array('filecontent' => $data));
```

At least in theory this would work. The reason why it does not work in practice is that `$data` is limited in size (must fit into the memory limit), and that JSON is not meant to transfer megabytes of data.

The encoding is inefficient. Either you use the bytes natively, then you will experience escape sequences for any non-printable character, making these bytes getting six times as big (the unicode escape sequence uses a backslash, the letter "u" and four hex numbers). Or you use base64 encoding, which will blow up EVERY byte by about 33%. Not counting the overhead for the most basic JSON wrapping.

Offering a native stream of bytes with an appropriate header seems to be the better idea. You could directly feed that stream into the video codec for replay, without having to parse JSON, decode base64 and reassemble everything back into a video data stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the info according to the PHP official documentation.
Hopefully it will work for the video file.

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverURL);
        MultipartEntity postEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        File file = new File("file path to be put here");
        postEntity.addPart("fileupload", new FileBody(file, "video/mp4"));
        postEntity.addPart("loginKey", new StringBody(""+loginKey));
        postEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(message));
        postEntity.addPart("token", new StringBody(token));
        post.setEntity(postEntity);
        response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: This code is for uploading the image to a server. My requirement is send image/video through PHP webservice. In-fact you got a point for the above. But the question sending the data as webservice in JSON format.(That can be anything)

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for you.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);//
    FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(file);
    StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + filename);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are receiving the file path of video in your webservice rather than whole video audio file in webservice, as in case of receiving the whole file the limit may exceded and you will be receiving invalid JSON response from PHP. So its safer to retrieve the file path of video on server rather than the video itself in response.

Another way is that you to use a webview and put a download link as in php in case of video file to download .

Answer (score 0):

You can encode any binary file into base64 and then output a JSON string like this:

```
<?php
$fgc = file_get_contents('yourfile.gif'); //can be any binary
$bindata = base64_encode($fgc);
$arr = array('name'=>'yourfile.gif','mime'=>'image/gif','data'=>$bindata);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

for video, use your preferable mime type...

at the Android side, decode the data and use the mime type so select proper view etc'...